# Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression Update Statement

Tags: vb.net, updates, oledbcommand

It replies Syntax error `(missing operator) in query expression on the executereader`
this is the value i get when i run the query.

```
"Update [Birthdays] set [ID] = 'RH1' where [ID] = 'RH' and [Date] = '1/1/2014' and [Description] = 'New Year's Day'"
```

Any error on my query? Thanks in advance.

This is my code:

```
Private Sub DGHolidays_CellEnter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DGHolidays.CellEnter
    Dim Row = DGHolidays.CurrentRow.Index
    col1 = DGHolidays.Rows(Row).Cells(0).Value()
    col2 = DGHolidays.Rows(Row).Cells(1).Value()
    col3 = DGHolidays.Rows(Row).Cells(2).Value()
End Sub

Private Sub DGHolidays_CellValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DGHolidays.CellValueChanged
    Dim Row = DGHolidays.CurrentRow.Index
    Dim ColI = DGHolidays.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex
    Dim Col = DGHolidays.Columns(ColI).HeaderText
    If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        con.Open()
    End If
    MessageBox.Show(DGHolidays.Rows(Row).Cells(ColI).Value.ToString())
    Dim updatehol As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("Update [Birthdays] set [" & Col & "] = '" & DGHolidays.Rows(Row).Cells(ColI).Value.ToString() & "' where [ID] = '" & col1 & "' and [Date] = '" & col2 & "' and [Description] = '" & col3 & "'", con)
    updatehol.ExecuteReader()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Erros is coz of

1. [Description] = 'New Year's Day', so you should escape the single quotes.
2. You should use `updatehol.ExecuteNonquery()` instead of `updatehol.ExecuteReader()`

**`ExecuteNonQuery()`**

1. will work with Action Queries only (Create,Alter,Drop,Insert,Update,Delete).
2. Returns the count of rows effected by the Query.
3. Return type is int
4. Return value is optional and can be assigned to an integer variable.

**`ExecuteReader()`**

1. will work with Action and Non-Action Queries (Select)
2. Returns the collection of rows selected by the Query.
3. Return type is DataReader.
4. Return value is compulsory and should be assigned to an another object DataReader.

**`ExecuteScalar()`**

1. will work with Non-Action Queries that contain aggregate functions.
2. Return the first row and first column value of the query result.
3. Return type is object.
4. Return value is compulsory and should be assigned to a variable of required type.

[**Reference**](http://nareshkamuni.blogspot.in/2012/05/what-is-difference-between.html)

Comment: okay. so i found the error in the text from the database having qoutes. i just use a fuction to alter the string making it 'New Year''s Day'. thanks

Comment: @MarkDave - Which is not the best way to accomplish it.  You should use a parameterized query instead so you don't have to worry about it.    Plus your code may be vulnerable to sql injection attacks.